# CreateObject("WXZ.Agent.1", "RemoteServerName") Permission denied. How can a username and password be supplied?

Tags: vbscript

Hi I'm trying to use CreateObject to DCOM to a service running on a remote machine. I get the error "Permission denied: 'CreateObject'", which is kind of what I expected.

I'm wondering though, how can I supply credentials to this call of a user who I know has permissions on the target machine to create the object? Is this possible? Or do I have to be logged on as a user who has the right permissions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't supply credentials for use in CreateObject.

One way to handle this is to create a specific Group in AD for access to the component and then ensure all users that need access to the component are members of that Group.